# Getting java gui to open a webpage in web browser

Tags: java, html, user-interface

I am trying to get a java gui to open a web page. So the gui runs some code that does things and then produces a html file.
I then want this file to open in a web browser (preferrably Firefox) as soon as it is created. 
How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 40):

If you're using Java 6 or above, see the [Desktop](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) API, in particular [browse](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI)). Use it like this (not tested):

```
// using this in real life, you'd probably want to check that the desktop
// methods are supported using isDesktopSupported()...

String htmlFilePath = "path/to/html/file.html"; // path to your new file
File htmlFile = new File(htmlFilePath);

// open the default web browser for the HTML page
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());

// if a web browser is the default HTML handler, this might work too
Desktop.getDesktop().open(htmlFile);
```

Comment: Hey. Still can't get it to work. I get the following error: "Error message: The system cannot find the path specified." This is even though I have given it the exact path.

Comment: @TheSpecialOne - are you supplying a _local_ path to the file? eg: on a windows box, htmlFilePath would look like "c:\path\to\file.html". Don't use the URL syntax...

Answer (score 27):

Ya, But if you want to open the webpage in your default web browser by a java program then you can try using this code.

```
/// file OpenPageInDefaultBrowser.java
public class OpenPageInDefaultBrowser {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
         //Set your page url in this string. For eg, I m using URL for Google Search engine
         String url = "http://www.google.com";
         java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
       }
       catch (java.io.IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
   }
}
/// End of file
```

Answer (score 3):

I know that all of these answers have basically answered the question, but here is a the code for a method that fails gracefully.

Note that the string can be the location of an html file

```
/**
* If possible this method opens the default browser to the specified web page.
* If not it notifies the user of webpage's url so that they may access it
* manually.
* 
* @param url
*            - this can be in the form of a web address (http://www.mywebsite.com)
*            or a path to an html file or SVG image file e.t.c 
*/
public static void openInBrowser(String url)
{
    try
        {
            URI uri = new URL(url).toURI();
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
            if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
                desktop.browse(uri);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Desktop not supported, cannout open browser automatically");
            }
        }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
            /*
             *  I know this is bad practice 
             *  but we don't want to do anything clever for a specific error
             */
            e.printStackTrace();

            // Copy URL to the clipboard so the user can paste it into their browser
            StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(url);
            Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            clpbrd.setContents(stringSelection, null);
            // Notify the user of the failure
            WindowTools.informationWindow("This program just tried to open a webpage." + "\n"
                + "The URL has been copied to your clipboard, simply paste into your browser to access.",
                    "Webpage: " + url);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used [BrowserLauncher2](http://browserlaunch2.sourceforge.net/) with success. It'll invoke the default browser on all platforms tested. I use this for demoing software via JNLP. The software downloads, runs and drives the user's browser to information pages/feedback etc.

JDK 1.4 and above, I believe.

Comment: If the URL of page get changed because of user activity can get that new URL using BrowserLauncher2?