# How do you open web pages in Java?

Tags: java, web, jframe

Is there a simple way to open a web page within a GUI's JPanel?

If not, how do you open a web page with the computer's default web browser?

I am hoping for something that I can do with under 20 lines of code, and at most would need to create one class. No reason for 20 though, just hoping for little code...

I am planning to open a guide to go with a game. The guide is online and has multiple pages,  but the pages link to each other, so I am hoping I only have to call one URL with my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting java gui to open a webpage in web browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602032/getting-java-gui-to-open-a-webpage-in-web-browser)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360744/how-to-render-basic-html-markup-inside-a-jpanel-in-java-swing

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Opening a web page with the default web browser is easy:

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(theURI);
```

Embedding a browser is not so easy. `JEditorPane` has *some* HTML ability (if I remember my limited Swing-knowledge correctly), but it's very limited and not suiteable for a general-purpose browser.

Comment: Desktop API is only for java 1.6

Comment: @dfa: so? There was no requirement for anything earlier and it's reasonable to use up-to-date APIs.

Comment: Note that if your URI is a string, you need to wrap it with `new java.net.URI(the URI)`

Comment: This solution is not cross-platform, this thread is better answering this question: [How to open the default webbrowser using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226212/how-to-open-the-default-webbrowser-using-java)

Comment: @CleberJorgeAmaral this is as cross platform as it gets. The top answer on the question you linked to uses the same class as my answer here.

Answer (score 2):

There are two standard ways that I know of:

1. The standard [`JEditorPane`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) component
2. [`Desktop`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html).[`getDesktop()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#getDesktop()).[`browse(URI)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI)) to open the user's default browser (Java 6 or later)

   Soon, there will also be a third:
3. The [`JWebPane`](http://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/html_component) component, which apparently has not yet been released

`JEditorPane` is very bare-bones; it doesn't handle CSS or JavaScript, and you even have to handle hyperlinks yourself. But you can embed it into your application more seamlessly than launching FireFox would be.

Here's a sample of how to use hyperlinks (assuming your documents don't use frames):

```
// ... initialize myEditorPane
myEditorPane.setEditable(false); // to allow it to generate HyperlinkEvents
myEditorPane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
        if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ENTERED) {
            myEditorPane.setToolTipText(e.getDescription());
        } else if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.EXITED) {
            myEditorPane.setToolTipText(null);
        } else if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
            try {
                myEditorPane.setPage(e.getURL());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // handle error
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Just curious, but how could I have improved this answer?

Comment: saua said "JEditorPane has some HTML ability, but it's very limited and not suiteable for a general-purpose browser." so i just went with the more simplistic one line of code saua posted... I was not going for something very nice looking, i am just trying to put together something that functions

Comment: I will probably give your code a try later on, but i did not try to run it... so i did not want to click that it was an answer since i don't actually know

Comment: Well, I also gave you saua's way before saua posted it. That's what the last sentence is referring to (did I make it unclear?).

Comment: yea, i saw them both at the same time and he had the code in the box thing, so it stuck out more.. i did not realize you posted the same thing..

Comment: i tend to read the starts of something which i kinda expect to be a quick summary of the rest of the post... so i guess you could mention the different methods at the beginning and then explain each one after that

Comment: Good point. (And thanks for answering the question in my first comment!)

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing an applet, you can use [AppletContext.showDocument](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument(java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String)). That would be a one-liner:

```
getAppletContext().showDocument("http://example.com", "_blank");
```

If you're developing a desktop application, you might try [Bare Bones Browser Launch](http://www.centerkey.com/java/browser/).

Answer (score 0):

haven't tried it at all, but the [cobra HTML parser and viewer](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra/getting-started.jsp) from the [lobo browser](http://lobobrowser.org/), a browser writen in pure java, may be what you're after. They provide sample code to set up an online html viewer:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import org.lobobrowser.html.gui.*;
import org.lobobrowser.html.test.*;

public class BareMinimumTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    HtmlPanel panel = new HtmlPanel();
    window.getContentPane().add(panel);
    window.setSize(600, 400);
    window.setVisible(true);
    new SimpleHtmlRendererContext(panel, new SimpleUserAgentContext())
    .navigate("http://lobobrowser.org/browser/home.jsp");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if such a built-in exists, but I would use the [Runtime](http://www.ida.liu.se/~TDDB32/kursbibliotek/BlueJ/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class's **exec** with iexplore.exe or firefox.exe as an argument.

Comment: If you do it with Runtime you would need to know wich browser the user runs. Hardly the best option

Comment: So you check for the presence of 3 browsers. I never said this was the best option.

Answer (score -3):

Please try below code :

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxExaception;

//below is the code
//whatvever the url is it has to have https://

Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
try {
    d.browse(new URI("http://google.com"));
} catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
```