# How to render basic HTML markup inside a JPanel in Java Swing?

Tags: html, swing, jpanel, java

I want to do something really simple like this:

```
JPanel htmlPanel = new HtmlPanel("<html><body><h1>hello world</h1></body></html>");
```

I think I had seen code somewhere that did exactly this. What about CSS and JS? Can the JPanel be made to support this easily? Are there libraries somewhere that do what I am asking for?

Comment: todays Java 1.6xxx suported Html <= 3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [here](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/how-add-style-stylesheet-jeditorpane-example-code) to see how to add CSS support to your **JEditorPane**. You will need an [HTMLEditorKit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html).

I do not see why you would need JavaScript support for a JEditorPane. The basic use of it is to render Help pages written in HTML and CSS.

If you need to have the real McCoy embedded into your application, try the [Lobo Java Web Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xamj/). Lobo does JavaScript and CSS and is open source 100% Java.

**November 2015**: The latest fork of the Lobo Browser is [Lobo Evolution](http://sourceforge.net/projects/loboevolution/).

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you were thinking of the `JEditorPane`. It can display html from e.g. an URL. 
[Swing tutorial, Editor panes.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

The support for javascript is nonexistent.

You can try out third party components such as [flying-saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/), which is a XML/XHTML and CSS 2.1 renderer in pure Java.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still looking for an easy solution to just enable display of HTML-Markup: Use a JLabel and enclose the text in '<html>' and '</html>' (body tag isn't needed).

Have a look at [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html). I just came across this when looking for an easy way to display data in tables, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

There was [JWebPane](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/waiting_for_jwebpane), a Java component based on WebKit, but that project seems to have died a long time ago and/or has just gone quiet. Some people are still hoping it will be released, The other one I know of is [WebKit for SWT](http://www.genuitec.com/about/labs-webkit-for-swt/WebKit%20For%20SWT%20Developer%20Guide.html), but it appears to be for Win32 only. :(