# How to embed web page into applet

Tags: java, html, applet

Just little half theoretical question. Is it possible to embed web page from URL into java applet?

Applet `applet1` is on `page1.html` on `server1` and I want to embed `applet1` into `page1.html` on `server1`. And in `applet1` would be `page2.html` on `server2` embedded. If it is possible how to do it? I need to use applet for embedding `page2.html` instead of `iframe` because of mouse tracking over `page2.html` for example.

Comment: I find your explanation very confusing.  DYM that page1 loads the applet which in turn loads page2 (in the applet content pane)?  Server 1 & 2 are on different domains?  Do you control the content of page2? *"because of mouse tracking over page2.html"* What does that mean?  Why are you trying to track the mouse?  What is is about an iframe that interferes with that?  Note that when you ask 2 questions & get 4+ questions back in a comment, it is a warning sign of a poorly expressed question.

Answer (score 2):

You can add html from site to panel of applet, but it will be not analog of iframe. This solution has problem with display html with css and another problems.

Maybe this will be helpful: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360744/how-to-render-basic-html-markup-inside-a-jpanel-in-java-swing) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790500/render-html-in-swing-application)