# Show output in html format

Tags: java, sql

I am using `SQLLite` database. I am trying to retrieve data in `HTML` format.
I am able to retrieve data in normal way, but I want the data I retrieve using query that data must be shown in `HTML` format. Can you please help me ?.

Comment: Is this Swing tag correct ? How is this question Swing related ?

Comment: Ops, I edit before I had read your comment. I assume that it had not to do with Swing.

Comment: Is the data in db in html format?

Comment: Since it is about "showing output", I can assume the Swing tag was correct, but the question isn't precise...

Comment: Your question is very vague... You cannot retrieve data from a database as HTML. But you can retrieve it as "data" and then enrich it with html metadata. I think your question can simply not be answered. Do you want to output it on a website?

Comment: Indeed, is the data stored as HTML text in the database, or do you want to wrap the raw data with HTML following some template?

Answer (score 1):

If, per the original tagging, your question is "how to display HTML in Swing", if you limit yourself to simple HTML, you can just display it in a JLabel which supports rudimentary formatting.

A simple quick search bring back to Stackoverflow (as often) to the topic: [How to render basic HTML markup inside a JPanel in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360744/how-to-render-basic-html-markup-inside-a-jpanel-in-java-swing)