# i want to create the program of the java when enter the link of the website and that link open in to browser

Tags: java, applet

i am new learner of java i want to create one application program in applet. i want to create
"applet which has a Text Field to accept a URL string, and displays the document of the URL string in a new browser window."

Thanks in advance.

@nimit parekh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From inside your applet class (which must extend java.awt.Applet or javax.swing.JApplet):

```
getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("http://www.google.com"));
```

Answer (score 1):

this post contains answer to your question:

[Getting java gui to open a webpage in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602032/getting-java-gui-to-open-a-webpage-in-web-browser)