# Parsing Text in Java from a Webpage that uses JavaScript to Generate the Text on-the-fly

Tags: java, javascript, parsing, url

I like playing Magic: The Gathering, and I also have a database of my collection. Magic set information was easy to obtain, since I could parse it directly from the HTML URL stream I opened, but I'm now trying to obtain prices for the cards as well from Star City Games (a MTG vendor). However, when I view source, there are no prices in the HTML; it's all done through JavaScript on-the-fly. Here's an example page for reference: http://sales.starcitygames.com/search.php?substring=Snapcaster+Mage&t_all=All&start_date=2010-01-29&end_date=2012-04-22&order_1=finish&limit=25&action=Show%2BDecks&card_qty%5B1%5D=1&auto=Y

The webpage generates the following HTML: http://pastebin.com/Psrpri8r .
I just want to be able to read the text "24.99." All of the code I'm using is in Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run javascript... Try [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

If you dont want to learn him, i've an Hacky solution (Warning: very complicated): Download the page to your computer (Download also all the .JS pages), Edit the JS code that send the relevant data to your server instead showing it, And [open this page in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602032/getting-java-gui-to-open-a-webpage-in-web-browser).