# Give command-line prompt from java

Tags: java

Some context: I am trying to access a router from a java program and I want to access it via a web browser. The easiest way I can think of is sending a command to the command-line, but none of the code that I have been using has worked thus far.

the method that I'm using is:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime.exec();
```

I'm not sure what command I should enter. Any suggestions?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I need a Mac and Windows version.

Comment: Regarding opening a web browser this might be interesting (it isn't command line but does open a browser); [Getting java gui to open a webpage in web browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602032/getting-java-gui-to-open-a-webpage-in-web-browser). What you want to do after that is less clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you have to do is open a browser you can do

```
Runtime  rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe google.com");
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Any chance that you could provide a command for mac as well? I need to have a mac and windows version.

Comment: Not sure about mac. Never used one. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

That command will take command line arguments. The arguments depend on the operating system you're running on. This is one of those questions where the answer is "it depends".

See [this question](http://www.coderanch.com/t/419192/java/java/Runtime-getRuntime-exec-String-command) for some background info.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question well, but if it is : "How do we execute a command from a Java program" here is an example :

```
public void execCmd()
{
    ProcessBuilder pB = new ProcessBuilder("copy file1 file2");
    Process p = pB.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [AWT Desktop#browse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29) method will open a given URL in the current user's default browser in a cross-platform manner:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;

...

Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://whatever/"));
```

This of course requires that your Java program be running in an interactive session.