# How to embed a web server in a java class?

Tags: java

Applications like H2 DB run cmd prompt and then open a webpage on 8082 port number.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: So how is it possible to write a program to display simple webpage in browser?

Comment: You will need a webserver that H2 uses. See [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H2 DB is running an embedded web server so that you you can manage it.

If your application needs to serve web pages then you cab use jetty which you can embed right in your code: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/

You can open a url or a local file in a browser using the answers here:

[Getting java gui to open a webpage in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602032/getting-java-gui-to-open-a-webpage-in-web-browser)

Comment: Yes, embedded web server. Got this link when searching for it. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128145/Run-Jetty-Web-Server-Within-Your-Application