# Open Url in given browser using process builder

Tags: java, macos, url, browser, processbuilder

My use case is to use process builder in java springboot to open a test url in google chrome. I have explored various commands to do the same but not able to achieve a desired result. I have explored the following ways to achieve the same. Can anyone suggest some more way of doing this both in Mac & Windows?

I have tried these 2 things, but will need a more robust way of doing it.

Error that I am receiving while using it :

```
/home/dell/Dokument/GitHub/Vaadin-DL4J-YOLO-Camera-Mail-Reporter/Vaadin-DL4J-YOLO-Camera-Mail-Reporter/Darknet/darknet
detect
cfg/yolov2-tiny.cfg
weights/yolov2-tiny.weights
data/cameraSnap.png
-thresh 0.3
ERROR!
Exited with error code : 0
```

I am using these 2 methods in IntelliJ:

```
ProcessBuilder ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./xyz", "devices", "-l")
```

OR

```
ProcessBuilder ProcessBuilder pb =
   new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do this in both mac & windows ?

Comment: Neither of your calls contains an url?!

Comment: Not (yet) a Java question. You should develop heuristics to find the correct paths in Powershell and bash first

Comment: Are you sure you need Chrome?  If you just want to use the user’s preferred browser, Java SE can do that for you quite easily with the `Desktop.browse` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what u r asking but I can share some commands which u can try to open a URL in a given browser using process builder in mac.
(for windows)
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start", browser, url);

(for mac)
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("open", "-a", browser, url);

Comment: I don't know about the Mac one, but the Windows command is more likely to open the link in Edge

Answer (score 0):

Yes the commands works , also some other options have various functionality
-e : open text edit
-f : read input from standard input.
Also whicle testing in google chrome use Google%20Chrome but in other cases we can use Safari & Firefox as usual browser names.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want/need to force the user to a specific browser?

For cross-platform stuff it is usually a bad idea to use command-line instructions via process builder, because the commands will always differ a bit for different operation systems.

Could you use the `Desktop` API? `Desktop.browse()` will open any URL you give it in the users default browser.

---

See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/602045/10875738

Snippet:

```java
import java.awt.Desktop;

//...

void showGoogle() {
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL("http://www.google.com").toURI());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```